# Storing a date and this date - 3 days with d3.js

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I'm having trouble with d3 once again.

Basically, I need to pass to a function two dates:

- one obtained by clicking on a bubble somewhere
- and the other, 3 days before the first one.

Both of these must be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

So far, here is what I've got:

```
 console.log(d.Date); //2014-05-01 
 console.log(d.date);  //Thu May 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) 
 console.log(d3.time.day.offset(d.date, 3)); //Sun May 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

So `offset` seems to work fine, but I really need these two dates in a different format.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 can format the dates for you like this:

```
formatter = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
formatter(d3.time.day.offset(new Date, 3)); // Returns "2014-06-27" (and today is the 24th!)
```

Reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: Thank you very much. How nice from these things to behave both as functions and objects!